# O que significa %=?

Tags: python, python-2.7, operadores

Possuo um codigo que contem a situação abaixo:

```
id %= 1000
```

Mas não sei a função desse operador.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

É o operador composto de atribuição e cálculo do módulo (obtenção do resto da divisão). Essencialmente é o mesmo que dizer:

```
id = id % 1000
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/Mod.py).

Isto está dividindo `id` por 1000, e atribuindo o resto obtido para a própria `id`.

Os operadores compostos fazem uma operação seguida de uma atribuição. A operação é o primeiro caractere antes do sinal de igual.

Falo essencialmente porque tem linguagens que isto não é uma verdade absoluta, a semântica pode ser um pouco diferente em alguns casos.

Algumas pessoas acham que isto é só açúcar sintático, e na maioria dos casos hoje em dia é mesmo, mas nem sempre, e no passado era diferente. Hoje costuma ser só uma forma contraída de escrever, mas era comum este operador oferecer mais performance que a forma extensa já que os compiladores não costumavam fazer muitas otimizações.

Então antes de achar que é exatamente a mesma coisa, consulte a implementação do compilador/interpretador da sua linguagem.

Answer (score 3):

Existe também a função divmod, que te retorna o resultado da divisão e o resto da mesma.

```
>>> divmod(3, 2)
(1, 1)
>>>
```

Answer (score -2):

Seria o resto da divisão:

1. `(1 % 3) = 1`
2. `(1 % 5) = 1`
3. `(1 / 3) = 1.5`
4. `(1 / 5) = 2.5`

Comment: 1 dividido por 5 dá 2,5?