# Qual a função de += na linguagem C?

Tags: c, característica-linguagem

estava em um exercício proposto por meu professor de Linguagem, e em certo momento me deparei com a função:

"somaImpares += i;"

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Também https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99184/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201424/101

Comment: Expressão equivalente a "somaImpares = somaImpares + i;". Esta é uma característica bem básica da linguagem e você com certeza encontraria milhões de informações referentes a ela numa busca rápida. Por favor, evite de perguntar na StackOverflow antes de procurar no próprio fórum ou no Google.